# Idea terminal shows wrong gradle version

Tags: windows, gradle, intellij-idea

When I open cmd and execute command `gradle -version`

It responds with gradle 4.6

When I open idea terminal in idea - it returns `gradle 2.8`.

I woriking on windows. System variable `GRADLE_HOME` and `PATH` are set properly. in Idea in gradle setings I pointed to gradle 4.6.

If in Idea I use gradle plugin it uses gradle 4.6 so problem only in idea terminal.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check `PATH` in the command line and in the Terminal, is it the same?

Answer (score 0):

Does this link on upgrading the gradle wrapper help?
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:upgrading_wrapper

`./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 4.6`